# static content rendering with spring mvc

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I am new to spring and am trying it.

I have a jsp file which includes css and images as follows

```
<link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

Now i have a  url path as `/localhost/myapp/test/tst` which is mapped to a controller which then forwards it to  view jsp

view.jsp is present it

```
/web-inf/jsp/view.jsp
```

But when hit the path `/localhost/myapp/test/tst` the css and images path gets resolved to

```
/localhost/myapp/test/tst/css/style.css
```

Actaully i want it to come as   `/localhost/myapp/css/style.css`
css and html are present in root of webapp

How i have following in my spring config

```
 <mvc:annotation-driven />
    <mvc:resources mapping="/images/**" location="/images/" />
    <mvc:resources mapping="/css/**" location="/css/" />
```

Comment: why don't you use `<link href="/css/style.css"` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your CSS href is currently relative to your page, you need to make it relative to the server root by adding a leading slash (plus context, etc). Its also a good idea to add the contextPath so that if/when you change the webapp name or deploy it as a root webapp, the resources still work.

```
<link href="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```